# Возможно ли через php отправить сообщение на телефон? Может есть код?

Tags: php

Подскажите, как через php отправить уведомление на телефон.

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно воспользоваться СМС-шлюзом. Как правило, они платные. [sms.ru](http://sms.ru), [sms-center.ru](http://sms-center.ru) и другие.

Разные шлюзы предоставляют разный протокол. Большинство работают по HTTP, есть те, что работает по SMTP (как с почтой).

Можно к серверу подключить 3g-модем и консольными командами (через `exec()` и прочие функции) посылать СМС. Но Ваш тариф в этом случае должен разрешать автоматизированную отправку СМС, это не каждый оператор одобряет.